# run ip commands without sudo

Tags: permissions, sockets, can

I am currently writing something that utilizes a usb CAN interface to communicate with a CAN bus. If I switch users to root, the program runs just fine, however, I want to run the program as my local user (steven). The program is built on top of libsocketcan (https://github.com/lalten/libsocketcan) which is where the commands that I need permission for are called.
specifically:
`can_set_bitrate, can_do_start`

I have tried adding permissions to my sudoers file as it is shown here, however that did not change the outcome:

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias ADMIN_CMDS = /usr/sbin/passwd, /usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/userdel, /usr/sbin/usermod, /usr/sbin/visudo, /usr/bin/link, /sbin/ip
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
steven ALL =(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I have also tried aliasing the ip command with `sudo ip` but that also has not solved the problem.
I keep running into this error specifically: `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`
Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure your library is actually running the `ip` command. It might be making the appropriate calls itself from C.

Comment: would you have a suggestion as to what I may need to give permissions for/allow access to?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might want to look into `setcap`, which could give the binary permission to access the socket. (I took a brief look and didn't figure out which capability it needs, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If your program runs /bin/ip, you can try setting the setuid sticky bit.

```
▶ sudo chmod u+s /bin/ip
```

Any user on the computer will be able to execute /bin/ip with root privileges.